# Android - webView: Web page not availale

Tags: android

I am trying to convert a web page into an app, but it is showing web page not available despite of how many links(url) I provided...
here is my .java file

```
package com.example.prem.webview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.easyolineconverter.com");
        //line of code for opening links in app
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

here is my manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.prem.webview">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use this:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

as shown below, in your Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ....... (Write Here)
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hopefully your problem will be solved.

Comment: I tried it before but it is showing error regarding some version

Comment: can you please update your manifest in your question after the changes which I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: I tried it myself in my system after adding cleartext line and it worked for me

Comment: yes I used it... Its still showing web page not available with error:ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @premkumar Instead of "http://www.easyolineconverter.com" try "http://www.google.co.in" ..... "http://www.easyolineconverter.com" This website is not loading in Mozilla even.. Try opening google.co.in in your webview.. include clearText too..

Comment: yes it worked... so does this mean all web pages cant be opened as app??

Comment: try opening it in chrome or mozilla it will not work.

Comment: @premkumar If you have got what you wanted, consider accepting the answer.. :)

Comment: Thank you.. try some website which exists and it will work @premkumar